# Bootstrap 3.3.7 change hover / active color of collapsed stack in navbar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v3.3.7

Trying to customize the navbar color using the page at:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/

Everything works EXCEPT when the navbar is collapsed down, ie:

```
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
```

The icon-bar(s), when collapsed appear as follows (which is fine):

[image: navbar with background color changed]

BUT, when I hover over the icon-bar(s), they appear washed-out, i.e.:

[image: navbar collapsed - hover/active not working]

Obviously the hover / active background and foreground colors need to be tweaked, but what are the magic LESS variables that need to be changed?

The goal is to keep the bars white and the background blue during hover / click, etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to both who replied -- the following did the trick:

```
  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus,
  .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover {
     background-color: transparent;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can customize it through the customize page but you can just target and override the button style through css.  I believe you will have to specify which navbar you are using so if you are using `.navbar-default` then you would do something like the following:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover{
  background:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try     `background-color: transparent;` like this

```
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus, 
.navbar .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```